# How to check which value is checked on the hidden tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, custom-object

I'm relatively new in JS and I have one question.
Basically I'm trying to access filed in a tab that is not visible on the page.

I'm  working on a questionnaire in which user answers on one of the questions by selecting radio button.
Radio button has ten possible answers (1-10) , and depending on the answer, the same number of tabs will appear.

Example:  If the users answers with 1, one tab will open with additional question with "yes" "no" option. If the user answers with 2, two tabs will appear but only first will be visible on the page. User can access the second tab by clicking on it, but in that case tab 1 won't be visible any more. Maybe picture below will clarify more.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VebuD.png)

**Shortly, what I'm trying to do is to check which value is checked on the hidden tab.**

I'm giving example of my code bellow if the user answers with 1 or 2 in initial question
This code works it the user selects 1 as initial response as it goes only if first IF statement

JS:

var QA_0, QA_1, Q1_0, Q1_1, Q2_0, Q2_1;

//QA_0 and QA_1 represent initial question  _0 is for answer 1, _1 is for the answer 2

//Q1_0 and Q1_1 are values on the first tab   _0 is for answer Yes, _1 is for the answer No

//Q2_0 and Q2_1 are values on the second tab  _0 is for answer Yes, _1 is for the answer No

function getAnswers() {
CheckVariable = false;

```
                    if (QA_0=document.getElementById("master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_0").checked == true) {
                             Q1_0=document.getElementById("master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_0").checked;
                             Q1_1=document.getElementById("master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1").checked;
                       }
                       
                    else  {  Q1_0=document.getElementById("master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_0").checked;
                             Q1_1=document.getElementById("master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1").checked;
                             Q2_0=document.getElementById("master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxc_0").checked;
                             Q2_1=document.getElementById("master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1").checked; 
                       }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways to hide tabs in css.
one is `display:none` and `visibility:hidden`

`display:none` means will not appear on the page at all.

`visibility:hidden` means will not visible but space is allocated (still alive)

choose second strategy.
To keep `#master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_0` tag alive to save "checked" state.

Then, I recommend `data attribute` to save "checked"  state into tag.

[data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

so then html looks like below.

```html
<div 
id=master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_0 
style="visibility:hidden"
data-checked="true"> 
some tab 1 
</div>

<div 
id=master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_1 
style="visibility: visible" 
data-checked="false" > 
some tab 2
</div>

<div 
id=master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_2
style="visibility: visible"
data-checked="true" > 
some tab 3
</div>

<div 
id=master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_3
style="visibility:hidden"
data-checked="false" > 
some tab 4
</div>
```

then, retrieve it in javascirpt code just like you do.

```js
QA_0 = document.getElementById("master_DefaultContent_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx_0").checked
```

I'm not sure it helps but i hope it do :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know you are using jQuery or not.
So I created a snippet using pure javascript.

```
<form>
  <input type="button" onclick="hideAll()" value="RESET"></button>
  <input type="button" onclick="showAnswers()" value="Show Answer"></button>

  <p>Please select problem number:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="n1" name="problems" value="1">
  <label for="n1">1</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="n2" name="problems" value="2">
  <label for="n2">2</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="n3" name="problems" value="3">
  <label for="n3">3</label>

  <br><br><br>    

  <div id="t1_box" hidden>
  <p> Tab 1 </p>
    <input type="radio" id="t1_o1" name="t1_answer" value="yes">
    <label for="t1_o1">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="t1_o2" name="t1_answer" value="no">
    <label for="t1_o2">No</label><br>
    <input type="button" class="next" id="t1_" value="Close & Save"></input>
  </div>

  <div id="t2_box" hidden>
  <p> Tab 2 </p>
    <input type="radio" id="t2_o1" name="t2_answer" value="yes">
    <label for="t2_o1">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="t2_o2" name="t2_answer" value="no">
    <label for="t2_o2">No</label><br>
    <input type="button" class="next" id="t2_" value="Close & Save"></input>
  </div>
  
  <div id="t3_box" hidden>
  <p> Tab 3 </p>
    <input type="radio" id="t3_o1" name="t3_answer" value="yes">
    <label for="t3_o1">Yes</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="t3_o2" name="t3_answer" value="no">
    <label for="t3_o2">No</label><br>
    <input type="button" class="next" id="t3_" value="Close & Save"></input>
  </div>
  <p id="result"></p>
</form>

<script>

var problems = 0;
function hideAll() {
    document.getElementById("t1_box").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("t2_box").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("t3_box").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "";
}

function showAnswers() {
    var result = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= problems; i ++) {
        var tab = "t" + i;
        var answer = "";
        if (document.getElementById(tab + '_o1').checked) {
            answer = "yes";
        } else if (document.getElementById(tab + '_o2').checked) {
            answer = "no";
        } else {
            answer = "undefined";
        }
        result += tab + ": " + answer + "<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
}

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("next");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var prep = this.getAttribute("id");
        document.getElementById(prep + "box").style.display = "none";
    }, false);
}

document.getElementById("n1").addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("t1_box").style.display = "block";
    problems = 1;
}, false);
document.getElementById("n2").addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("t1_box").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("t2_box").style.display = "block";
    problems = 2;
}, false);
document.getElementById("n3").addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("t1_box").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("t2_box").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("t3_box").style.display = "block";
    problems = 3;
}, false);
</script>
```